# Richfaces3.3 file upload not working in Mozila Firefox

Tags: firefox, file-upload, richfaces

I am using Richfaces 3.3 along with jboss seam on jboss server. The file upload component works fine on chrome but the same component throws error on firefox browser and following is the stack trace, Could you please guide me what's issue here and how to fix it?

javax.servlet.ServletException

```
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:277)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)

at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:304)

at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:381)

at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:529)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:86)

at com.myapp.seam.web.filters.myappCSRFFilter.doFilter(myappCSRFFilter.java:44)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

at com.myapp.seam.web.filters.myappSecureHeaderFilter.doFilter(myappSecureHeaderFilter.java:63)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)

at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)

at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)

at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:73)

at com.myapp.seam.infrastructure.BaseUrlFilter.doFilter(BaseUrlFilter.java:123)

at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)

at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)

at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)

at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)

at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)

at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)

at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)

at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:404)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:40020)

at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)

at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)

at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)

at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)

at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)

at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)

at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)

at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at org.richfaces.renderkit.FileUploadRendererBase.doDecode(FileUploadRendererBase.java:139)

at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.decode(RendererBase.java:75)

at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:789)

at javax.faces.component.UIInput.decode(UIInput.java:725)

at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1031)

at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processDecodes(UIInput.java:639)

at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:209)

at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1026)

at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot$1.invokeContextCallback(AjaxViewRoot.java:400)

at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:240)

at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processDecodes(AjaxViewRoot.java:417)

at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)

at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)

at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)

at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
```

Let me know if you need any further info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [Richfaces fileuploader nullpointer firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52742539/richfaces-fileuploader-nullpointer-firefox ) I've the same issue has yours.

Comment: prignony, have you found any fix for this?

Comment: No sorry, we did not find a fix, instead we updated richfaces to a "better" version. I hope you'll find the answer